# Как упростить данный код? Если в файле 123456789, нужно чтобы в файл записалось 234567890

Tags: c++, файлы

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void my_task(istream& in, ostream& out)
{   
    char buffer;

    while (!in.eof())
    {
        
        while (in.get(buffer))
        {
            switch (buffer)
            {
            case '0':
                out << 1;
                break;
            case '1':
                out << 2;
                break;
            case '2':
                out << 3;
                break;
            case '3':
                out << 4;
                break;
            case '4':
                out << 5;
                break;
            case '5':
                out << 6;
                break;
            case '6':
                out << 7;
                break;
            case '7':
                out << 8;
                break;
            case '8':
                out << 9;
                break;
            case '9':
                out << 0;
                break;
            }
        }    
    }
}


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    ifstream in("in.txt");
    ofstream out("out.txt");

   
    if (!in.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
    }
    
    else
    {
        my_task(in, out);

        cout << "Result in Out.txt " << endl;

        in.close();

        out.close();

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вопрос в том, что делать, если в файле не только цифры, а, скажем, еще и перевод строки или буквы. Если только цифры - например, так:

```
void my_task(istream& in, ostream& out)
{   
    char buffer;
    while(in.get(buffer))
    {
        if (buffer++ == '9') buffer = '0';
        out << buffer;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ifstream in("in.txt");
    if (!in.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        ofstream out("out.txt");
        my_task(in, out);
        cout << "Result in Out.txt " << endl;
    }
}
```

Если есть еще и другие символы - добавить проверку `isdigit` на входе.

Кстати, вы делаете проверку, что открылся `in.txt` - а `out.txt` нет - нехорошо :)

Comment: Ошибки учту, за помощь огромное спасибо! Код никуда не отправлялся, просто не смог сложить 2+2, чтобы для 9 отдельное условие создать

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
void my_task(istream& in, ostream& out)
{   
    char buffer;
    while(in.get(buffer))
        out << char((buffer - '0' + 1)%10 + '0');
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]